Nginx rewrite after a proxy pass when conflict endpoints
I'm currently working on a Docker Compose setup that deploys three services: 2 FastAPI APIs (app1 and app2) and an Nginx reverse-proxy. Each FastAPI API has a Swagger documentation endpoint at /docs.
To route requests to the appropriate API, I'm using the rewrite directive in the Nginx configuration. However, I'm facing an issue when both APIs have the same endpoint, such as /docs.
Here's the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.8"

services:
  app_1:
    image: app_1
    build:
      context: ./app_1
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
  app_2:
    image: app_2
    build:
      context: ./app_2
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8002:8000 
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.24.0
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

And here's my nginx.conf configuration:
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /embeddings {
        proxy_pass http://app_2:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /app2/docs {
        rewrite ^/app2/docs /docs break;
        proxy_pass http://app_2:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

With this configuration, when I call the /app2/docs endpoint, it redirects me to the Swagger documentation for app1 (instead of app2). My interpretation is that when /app2/docs is rewritten as /docs, it is interpreted by the / location and therefore redirects to app1.
Is it possible to solve this problem with Nginx? If so, do you have any ideas on how I could modify my configuration to correctly route requests to the appropriate API?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Léo
